# Creating Properties in Obj-C, how do I write the default Getter?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, properties, getter-setter

I'm just starting to learn Objective-C, one thing I'm trying to learn is good Property use.  I'm currently trying to create some properties with custom setters.  This is how far I've gotten:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) int myNumber;
@end

@implementation MyClass
@dynamic myNumber;

- (int)myNumber {
    return ???;
}

- (void)setMyNumber:newNumber {
    myNumber = newNumber;
    // custom stuff here
}
```

I really just want to implement a custom setter, I'm fine with the getter being default.  However, how do I access the variable directly?  If I put "return self.myNumber", won't that just call the getter method and infinite loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property access functions are only called when using the `x.p` notation. You can access the instance variable backing the property with just `p` (in Objective C, all members have the class instance variables in scope). You can, if you really want, also access via the pointer deference notation `->`. So, any of these two:

```
return p;

return self->p;
```

However, you needn't use `@dynamic` here. `@synthesize` is smart, and will only create defaults if you've not provided them. So feel free to just

```
@synthesize p;
```

Which will create the getter, but not the setter in this case.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much!  I was under the impression that if you wanted your custom getters and setters you had to use `@dynamic`, but you're right, `@synthesize` is very smart!
I did try `self->p` at one point, but Xcode highlighted it with formatting I believed was an error.  Turns out it was just a warning saying "did you mean `self.p`?"

Answer (score 0):

```
- (int)myNumber {
    return myNumber;
}
```